# High error on training set when asked to predict on training set but average loss while training is low

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am training a model using vowpal wabbit and notice something very strange. During training, the average loss reported is very low somewhere around 0.06. However I notice that when I asked the model to predict labels on the same training data, the average loss is high around ~0.66 and the model performs poorly on predicting labels for even the training data. My initial conjecture was that the model suffered a high bias, and hence I increased the complexity of the model to use 300 hidden nodes in the first layer, but still the problem persists.

I would greatly appreciate pointers on what could be going on

The tutorial slides for VW mentions:
"If you test on the train set, does it work? (no
=> something crazy)"

So something very crazy seems to be happening and I am trying to understand where I should dig deeper possibly.

More details:
I am using vowpal wabbit for a named entity recognition task where features are word representations. I am trying several models using neural networks with multiple hidden units and trying to evaluate the model. However all of my trained models exhibit high average loss when tested on the training data itself which I find very odd.

Here is one way to reproduce the problem:

Output of training:

```
vw -d ~/embeddings/eng_train_4.vw --loss_function logistic --oaa 6 --nn 32 -l 10 --random_weights 1 -f test_3.model --passes 4 -c

final_regressor = test_3.model
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 10
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
using cache_file = /home/vvkulkarni/embeddings/eng_train_4.vw.cache
ignoring text input in favor of cache input
num sources = 1
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
0.666667   0.666667          3      3.0          1        1      577
0.833333   1.000000          6      6.0          1        2      577
0.818182   0.800000         11     11.0          4        4      577
0.863636   0.909091         22     22.0          1        4      577
0.636364   0.409091         44     44.0          1        1      577
0.390805   0.139535         87     87.0          1        1      577
0.258621   0.126437        174    174.0          1        1      577
0.160920   0.063218        348    348.0          1        1      577
0.145115   0.129310        696    696.0          1        1      577
0.138649   0.132184       1392   1392.0          1        1      577
0.122486   0.106322       2784   2784.0          1        1      577
0.097522   0.072557       5568   5568.0          1        1      577
0.076875   0.056224      11135  11135.0          1        1      577
0.058647   0.040417      22269  22269.0          1        1      577
0.047803   0.036959      44537  44537.0          1        1      577
0.038934   0.030066      89073  89073.0          1        1      577
0.036768   0.034601     178146 178146.0          1        1      577
0.032410   0.032410     356291 356291.0          1        1      577 h
0.029782   0.027155     712582 712582.0          1        1      577 h

finished run
number of examples per pass = 183259
passes used = 4
weighted example sum = 733036
weighted label sum = 0
average loss = 0.0276999
best constant = 0
total feature number = 422961744
```

Now when I evaluate the model above using the same data (used for training)

```
vw -t ~/embeddings/eng_train_4.vw -i test_3.model -p test_3.pred

only testing
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 10
initial_t = 1
power_t = 0.5
predictions = test_3.pred
using no cache
Reading datafile = /home/vvkulkarni/embeddings/eng_train_4.vw
num sources = 1
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
0.333333   0.333333          3      3.0          1        1      577
0.500000   0.666667          6      6.0          1        4      577
0.636364   0.800000         11     11.0          6        3      577
0.590909   0.545455         22     22.0          1        1      577
0.500000   0.409091         44     44.0          4        1      577
0.482759   0.465116         87     87.0          1        1      577
0.528736   0.574713        174    174.0          1        3      577
0.500000   0.471264        348    348.0          1        3      577
0.517241   0.534483        696    696.0          6        1      577
0.536638   0.556034       1392   1392.0          4        4      577
0.560345   0.584052       2784   2784.0          1        5      577
0.560884   0.561422       5568   5568.0          6        2      577
0.586349   0.611820      11135  11135.0          1        1      577
0.560914   0.535477      22269  22269.0          1        1      577
0.557200   0.553485      44537  44537.0          1        1      577
0.568938   0.580676      89073  89073.0          1        2      577
0.560568   0.552199     178146 178146.0          1        1      577

finished run
number of examples per pass = 203621
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 203621
weighted label sum = 0
average loss = 0.557428 <<< This is what is tricky.
best constant = -4.91111e-06
total feature number = 117489309
```

Things I have tried:
1.I tried increasing the number of hidden nodes to 600 but to no avail.
2.I also tried using quadratic features with 300 hidden nodes but that did not  help either.

The rationale behind trying 1.) and 2.) was to increase model complexity assuming that high training error was due to high bias.

Update:
Even more intrestingsly, if I however specify the number of passes to be 4 in the testing phase (even though I assumed the model would have learnt a decision boundary), then the problem goes away. I am trying to understand why ?

```
vvkulkarni@einstein:/scratch1/vivek/test$ vw -t ~/embeddings/eng_train_4.vw -i test_3.model -p test_3_1.pred --passes 4 -c
only testing
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 10
initial_t = 1
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
predictions = test_3_1.pred
using cache_file = /home/vvkulkarni/embeddings/eng_train_4.vw.cache
ignoring text input in favor of cache input
num sources = 1
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
0.333333   0.333333          3      3.0          1        1      577
0.166667   0.000000          6      6.0          1        1      577
0.090909   0.000000         11     11.0          4        4      577
0.045455   0.000000         22     22.0          1        1      577
0.022727   0.000000         44     44.0          1        1      577
0.011494   0.000000         87     87.0          1        1      577
0.017241   0.022989        174    174.0          1        1      577
0.022989   0.028736        348    348.0          1        1      577
0.020115   0.017241        696    696.0          1        1      577
0.043822   0.067529       1392   1392.0          1        1      577
0.031968   0.020115       2784   2784.0          1        1      577
0.031968   0.031968       5568   5568.0          1        1      577
0.032959   0.033950      11135  11135.0          1        1      577
0.029952   0.026944      22269  22269.0          1        1      577
0.029212   0.028471      44537  44537.0          1        1      577
0.030481   0.031750      89073  89073.0          1        1      577
0.028673   0.026866     178146 178146.0          1        1      577
0.034001   0.034001     356291 356291.0          1        1      577 h
0.034026   0.034051     712582 712582.0          1        1      577 h
```

Comment: You should include **much more** details. Short, reproducible code is required for any help

Comment: Thanks.I have added details on the model I have used. Also added command line I used along with their outputs to indicate the problem precisely and also what I have tried. Please let me know if any specific details are needed.

Comment: Are you really sure you're testing on the same data?  Note that the 'current label' is different between the two runs for the same example number, when I expect them to be the same on the same data.  Another suspect thing is that even after you create a cache for your training-set (training step) the test step doesn't seem to use the cache...

Comment: Just noticed another inconsistency: the combination of `--loss_function logistic` and `--oaa 6`, which I'm not sure makes sense.  When you use `-oaa` it is implied that you're trying to run a classification with 6 different labels.  `--loss_function logistic` implies a binary classifications with labels in {-1,1} which against 6 labels gives a large error. Since there are so many options (about 100 by now) `vw` doesn't have protection against every inconsistent combo.  I think You should be dropping the `--loss_function logistic` from the training command line.

Answer (score 1):

You have hash collisions because you have many more features than you have spaces in the hash.

The default hash size is 18 bits or 262144 spaces.  According to your first printout, there are 422961744 features which at a minimum requires 27 bits so you should add -b27 (or more) to your command line.

I don't have your input file so I cannot try it and see.. but here is one way to check for collisions:

Run your learning phase and add --invert_hash final
then check collisions with these lines:

```
tail -n +13 final | sort -n -k 2 -t ':' | wc -l
tail -n +13 final | sort -nu -k 2 -t ':' | wc -l
```

The values output should be the same.  I got this tip from John Langford, creator of Vowpal Wabbit.

Comment: Note that the 422961744 is total number of features seen during the run, not unique features.  So total/examples/passes = 422961744/183259/4 = 577 which is exactly the number of features per example.  SO I wouldn't suspect collisions here.